# Convert NSArray into Array of unique values sorted by frequency in Objective-C or Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, comparator, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of values where I would like to count the incidence of each unique value and then create a new array of unique value sorted by incidence.

For example, for the Array as follows:

```
 vals = {0,0,0,2,0,1,2}
```

I would like to end up with array of `{0,2,1}` since 0 is the most common value, 2 is the second most common and 1 is the least common. Note, the fact that these are numbers is irrelevant. They could just as easily be strings.

I thought I might be able to use an nssortdescriptor as in:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"wordCount" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedcats = [vals sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
```

However, this is not sorting them by incidence and it also does not filter out duplicates.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches

Convert to a `Set/NSSet` then sort.

Swift

```
let vals = [0,0,0,2,0,1,2]
let uniqued = Set(vals).sorted()
```

That same method would also work with `NSSet` + `NSSortDescriptor` in Objective C but obviously a longer line to write.

or a more classic Foundation approach

```
let nsvals: NSArray = [3,0,0,2,0,1,2]
let nsuniquedAndSorted = nsvals.value(forKeyPath: "@distinctUnionOfObjects.self")
```

Which is kind of cool as `@distinctUnionOfObjects` also sorts for free. There's lots of clever key-value tricks in the same vein [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html).

**EDIT**

To sort by incidence an approach could be to count the uniques then resort on that basis.

```
let sortedByIncidence = uniqued
    .map { outer in return (outer, vals.filter({$0 == outer}).count) }
    .sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
    .map { $0.0 }
```

Comment: I used second method. Very elegant.

Comment: @user6631314 I just noticed that this doesn't answer the question of sorting by frequency however. For that you'd probably want to attack  with maybe `reduce` or `zip` in Swift.

Comment: Yes, I just discovered that while it sorted for frequency in one example (I guess by chance) it did not do so in a second example. Thanks for edit solution.